# Assembly function basics?

Tags: function, assembly, stack

I need a little bit of help understanding some things on functions in assembly.  I can make a simple function that takes in a parameter or 2 and then returns something like a number by placing it in a register %eax.  My question is how do you return a list?  I am creating a function that will search through a defined data set of maybe 100 numbers and I need to keep running totals of the number of numbers in particular ranges (0-9, 10-19, 20-29, etc) so a variable for each range.  Since the number of registers is finite, I will obviously have to create space for the local variables by adjusting the stack and what not.  But, how do I return all of these values? I would assume you would return an address in %eax pointing to where these variables are, but since the values were local and created on the stack, wouldn't I not be able to access these?  I mean I guess you could, but that goes against everything I know about local variables and their scope.  Are these values supposed to be put on the heap or something?  I haven't been taught anything involving the heap for assembly, so I don't know if that's what I'm supposed to do or I'm not understanding something...?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many elements in the list/array there are going to be, you can just allocate memory for it either in that function (use C's `malloc()` or an equivalent) or outside of it (again, use `malloc()` or declare the array/list as a variable or a set of variables referencing one another) and pass the function the address of the first element of the list/array.

Alternatively, you could build the list/array element by element in the function and return from it the address of the first element. Naturally, you'll need to allocate the first element and then grow the allocation to have some room for subsequent elements (use C's `realloc()`) or you can allocate all elements individually (using C's `malloc()`) and chain them (that is, the elements would need to include a pointer/address for the purpose of chaining them into a list).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume by "list" that you mean "array".  If you want to return a pointer to an array of numbers, you'll need to allocate some memory for that array.  Either have the caller pass it in, or call `malloc` to allocate a buffer - it will work just as well for an assembly program as for a C program.  Finally, return the pointer to the array in `eax`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't think of doing the same thing I would do in C.  ...assembly -.-

Answer (score 0):

You return a memory index to a list created on the heap.  Or you pass it in a memory index to write the data to as a parameter, and use it as an output variable.  Then that memory index could be stack or heap based.

Comment: So you're saying I can return a memory index that would point to the variables I created in the function on the stack without using the heap?

Comment: @Jack - no, that would be pretty dangerous.  What if you call some other functions that modify those variables on the stack?

Comment: No, it would have to be a heap memory index or it could get overwritten (the same reason you can't return a pointer to a stack object in C++).  But if your calling function allocates the memory on the stack you can safely pass that index to the function.  The tradeoff there is that the calling function needs to know (or guess) how much memory to allocate ahead of time.